# Vlook up between different vba

Tags: vba, vlookup, between

I need your help. I have 2 different files, A and B. I need to find a Value from A file into a table I have on file B.
I tried 2 different options:

option 1:

```
Range("P2") = "=Vlookup(RC[11],('\\Vals02\iberia comp\[ARCHIVOS\DATA BASE.xlsx]Sheet1'!BELGICA),8,False)"
```

where "BELGICA" is the name of the table on file B and Range("P2") is located on file A

option 2:

```
    Dim Open_data_base As Workbook, Actual As Workbook, Rute As String, Close_data_base As Workbook
    Dim Tab_send As Worksheet, Tab_recieve As Worksheet
            
            Rute = "\\Server02\FILES\DATA BASE.xlsx"
            Set Open_data_base = Workbooks.Open(Ruta)
            Set Tab_send = Open_data_base.Sheets("Sheet1")
            Set Actual = ThisWorkbook
            Set Tab_receive = Actual.Sheets("Blad1")

    Ult_fila = Range(Range("R3"), Range("R3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 2
                        
                            For Line = 2 To Ult_fila
            
    Sheets("Tab_receive").Cells(Line, 16) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("Tab_receive").Cells(Line, 25), Application.Workbooks("DATA BASE.xlsx").Worksheets("Tab_send").Range("Belgica"), 8, False)
                          
                            Next Line
```

Comment: Is it a typo in your question or also in your code: You set the name of the workbook into variable `Rute` but use the (undeclared?) variable `Ruta` in the Open-statement. Are you using `Option Explicit`? Btw: You have a strange way of code indentation, makes it hard to read the code.

Comment: Sorry, It was a type mistake. I already tried RUTE, but doesn't work.